# How do I tell EF Core about two properties of the same type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a set of models representing legal cases. One of the actions a user can do on a case is generate a document. This action is saved as a `History` entity, with an associated `HistoryFile` entity that contains the data about the file. Other actions may result in a `History` entity, with zero or multiple associated `HistoryFile` entities.

Cut-down versions of these two classes looks like this...

```cs
  public class History {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<HistoryFile> HistoryFiles { get; set; }
  }

  public class HistoryFile {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int HistoryId { get; set; }
    public History History { get; set; }
  }
```

The next requirement is that a user can pick up on a document that was previously generated and continue working on it. The bit where I'm getting stuck is that the `HistoryFile` entity needs a reference back to the `History` entity that held the previous version. This means that I need to add two lines of code to the `HistoryFile` entity...

```cs
  public class HistoryFile {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int HistoryId { get; set; }
    public History History { get; set; }
    public int? PreviousHistoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual History PreviousHistory { get; set; }
  }
```

This means that there are two links from a `HistoryFile` to a `History`, one required one which is the parent `History` entity (via the `History` property) and an optional one via the `PreviousHistory` property.

I can't work out how to set this up for EF Core. As the code stands now, when I try to add a migration, I get the following error...

> Cannot create a relationship between 'History.HistoryFiles' and 'HistoryFile.PreviousHistory' because a relationship already exists between 'History.HistoryFiles' and 'HistoryFile.History'. Navigation properties can only participate in a single relationship. If you want to override an existing relationship call 'Ignore' on the navigation 'HistoryFile.PreviousHistory' first in 'OnModelCreating'.

I tried adding the following to my `DbContext`...

```cs
builder.Entity<HistoryFile>(entity => {
  entity.HasOne(hf => hf.History)
    .WithMany(h => h.HistoryFiles)
    .HasForeignKey(hf => hf.HistoryId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
  entity.HasOne(hf => hf.PreviousHistory)
    .WithMany(h => h.HistoryFiles)
    .HasForeignKey(hf => hf.PreviousHistoryId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
});
```

...but it didn't make any difference.

Anyone able to tell me how I configure this so that EF Core knows that there are two distinct links between the two entities?

I'm using EF Core 5.0.7 in a .NET5 project in case it makes a difference.

Thanks

Comment: Can't help but think this might be slightly easier managed as a History having N related HistoryFile (or a HistoryFile having N related Revision) -it's just a standard 1:M relationship then, rather than this "N HistoryFile with a current and previous.." - not sure what I'd call it, some kind of relational linked list structure maybe..

Comment: @CaiusJard The client specifically wants each revision to appear as a new history item, rather than seeing multiple revisions in the one History. There are good business reasons for this, mainly due to billing and accounting. Thanks anyway

Comment: The appearance and how the data is modelled are two completely separate things. You are responsible for both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.

I needed to add the following two lines to the `History` class...

```cs
public virtual ICollection<HistoryFile> HistoryFilesParentHistory { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<HistoryFile> HistoryFilesPreviousHistory { get; set; }
```

...and then change the code I added to the `DbContext` to look like this...

```cs
builder.Entity<HistoryFile>(entity => {
  entity.HasOne(hf => hf.History)
    .WithMany(h => h.HistoryFilesParentHistory)
    .HasForeignKey(hf => hf.HistoryId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
  entity.HasOne(hf => hf.PreviousHistory)
    .WithMany(h => h.HistoryFilesPreviousHistory)
    .HasForeignKey(hf => hf.PreviousHistoryId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
});
```

This worked fine.