# Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In this project, I have lots of devices, for example, d1, d2, d3. If `d1.currentVaue > 100`, then d2 write value 30, d3 write value 80.

This is the class:

```
public class Device
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public  string CurrentValue { get; set; }
    public List<Linkage> Linkages { get; set; }
}
```

and LinkAge:

```
public class Linkage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Device BelongPoint { get; set; }
    public Device WritePoint { get; set; }
    public string WriteValue { get; set; }
}
```

user Entity FrameworkCore，and add-migration, Error Infomation:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation
> 'Device.Linkages' of type 'List'. Either manually
> configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the
> '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in
> 'OnModelCreating'.

Google tells me use InverseProperty, but the Sample user 2 different collect, here only one collection, how to fix the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70559886/5045688

Comment: The data *content* has nothing to do with this error about a data-independent relationship configuration error. EF doesn't know which Device in Linkage associates with Device.Linkages, that's all. See the duplicate, only the wording of the exception message has changed, it's the same problem.